# XSLT to transform in a XML some tags with the count of every tag

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I transform an XML that has something like this:

```
<info>
   .....
   <name>aaa</name>
</info>
<info>
   .....
   <name>bbb</name>
</info>
<info>
   .....
   <name>ccc</name>
</info>
```

with an XSLT into something like this:

```
<info>
   .....
   <name1>aaa</name1>
</info>
<info>
   .....
   <name2>bbb</name2>
</info>
<info>
   .....
   <name3>ccc</name3>
</info>
```

Anyone has any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: WDrgn, it is a bad idea to add numeric values to the element names. It is much better to add a new attribute, like **@id="1"**, etc. to the name element.

Comment: yeah, but this is how it is needed... :( and I was wondering if I can do that somehow...

Comment: The `xsl:element` element and the `position()` function are your friends in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `xsl:number` instead of sibling count:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="info/name">
      <xsl:variable name="pos">
          <xsl:number count="info"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:element name="{name()}{$pos}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivJs7

Or in XSLT 3 use an accumulator (works even with streaming):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="info-count" streamable="yes"/>

  <xsl:accumulator name="info-count" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="info" select="$value + 1"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:template match="info/name">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}{accumulator-before('info-count')}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivJs7/1

Comment: Thank you a lot! it's working perfectly with xsl:number! can't use 3.0...

Answer (score 1):

One approach is using `count(...)` in combination with the `preceding-sibling::` axis:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- Identity template -->    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Modify all 'name' elements -->
    <xsl:template match="name">
      <xsl:element name="{concat(name(),count(../preceding-sibling::info)+1)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is as desired.